# Retrieve data if next line of data equals a particular value

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL and I need some assistance with a query.

I am writing a script which is reviewing a log file. Basically the query is retrieving the instance of when a particular status occurred. This is working as expected however I would like to now add a new condition which states that only if the immediate value after this value equals 'Accepted' or 'Attended'. How would I do this. I have pasted the current script below and commented in italics where I think this condition should be. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
WITH Test AS

(
Select  j.jobcode, min(log.timestamp) as 'Time First Assigned'
from Job J
inner join JobLog Log 
    on J.JobID = Log.JobID 
    and log.JobStatusID = 'Assigned' *-- and record after this equals accepted or attended*
where j.CompletionDate >= @Start_date 
  and j.CompletionDate < @End_date 
Group by j.jobcode
)
```

Comment: Sample data would greatly help you get your point across.

Comment: `LEAD() OVER ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend `lead()`, but using it in a subquery on one table:

```
with test as (
      select j.jobcode, min(log.timestamp) as time_first_assigned
      from Job j join
           (select jl.*,
                   lead(jl.JobStatusID) over (partition by jl.jobid order by jl.timestamp) as next_status
            from JobLog jl
           ) jl
           on J.JobID = Log.JobID 
       where jl.JobStatusID = 'Assigned' and
             jl.next_JobStatusID in ('accepted', 'attended') and
             j.CompletionDate >= @Start_date and
             j.CompletionDate < @End_date 
       group by j.jobcode
      )
```

In particular, this enables the optimizer to use an index on `JobLog(jobid, timestamp, JobStatusId)` for the `lead()`.  That said, this will not always improve performance, particularly if the filter on the `CompletionDate` filters out most rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEAD` windows function as follows:

```
Select  jobcode, min(ts) as 'Time First Assigned' from
(select j.jobcode, log.timestamp as ts, JobStatusID , 
        lead(log.JobStatusID) 
             over (partition by Log.JobID order by Log.timestamp) as lead_statusid
  from Job J
 inner join JobLog Log on J.JobID = Log.JobID 
 where j.CompletionDate >= @Start_date and j.CompletionDate < @End_date 
) t
where JobStatusID = 'Assigned' and lead_statusid in ('accepted', 'attended') 
Group by jobcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.

I used Gordon's suggested code and once I changed the values to the names I used in my code I can confirm that it works.

I did look at the Lead function however I didn't know how to apply it.

Again thanks to everyone for helping with my query.